# Repeat alarm one time (Alarm manager)

Tags: android, alarmmanager

i want to play music only one time but the code every minute play it how can i do that ?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button BT;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
public void func()
{
    AlarmManager alarmManager=(AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),1*60*1000,pendingIntent);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,sv.class);
    pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,0,intent,0);
    BT=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    BT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         func();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the the alarm type 'setInexactRepeating' - which as it suggests ... Repeats.  Try using 'set' instead. There is more info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work ... i want my alarm to repeat only one time

Comment: sorry misunderstood your question, you in fact want an alarm to go off twice, not once I understand?  you can pass extras in the intents you are wrapping with the pendingIntents so you could increment a int and each time your pendingIntent is fired from the alarms onReceive you could check this value is under your limit, if so, set another alarm, if not, cancel the alarm.